# Копирование двумерного массива в c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

В функции массив копируется для дальнейшего использования при возведении его в степень, но при компиляции выводит ошибку :"Вызвано исключение по адресу 0x00007FF6E7F3241E"
Код копирования:

```
void CMatr(double x[N][N], int k, double y[N][N])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (j = 0; i < k; j++) {
            y[i][j] = x[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Код функции возведения в степень:

```
void PowMatr(double x[N][N], int k, int l, double y[N][N])
{
    double yx[N][N];
    int i;
    CMatr(x, k, y);
    for (i = 2; i <= l; i++) {
        UMatr(y, x, k, yx);
        CMatr(y, k, yx);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

во втором for ты проверяешь i < k, нужно j < k

```
void CMatr(double x[N][N], int k, double y[N][N])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        for (j = 0; i < k; j++) {
            y[i][j] = x[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```